# Как они зарабатывают?

Tags: opensource

Наверное многие люди, которые имеют отношение к ИТ, хоть раз интересовались каким способом производиться получение прибыли с созданных программируемых объектов. Как зарабатывают на большинстве продуктов созданных такими гигантами как Microsoft или Apple, надеюсь ни у кого не вызывает вопросов(ведь софт они просто продают), а вот как обстоит ситуация с бесплатными программами, которые ко всему прочему не толкают рекламу? Взять к примеру ОС Ubuntu.

> Ubuntu в настоящее время финансируется
> Марком Шаттлвортом и основанной им
> компанией Canonical.

Цитата  из [википедии](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu#.D0.9A.D0.BB.D0.B0.D1.81.D1.81.D0.B8.D1.84.D0.B8.D0.BA.D0.B0.D1.86.D0.B8.D1.8F_.D0.BF.D0.B0.D0.BA.D0.B5.D1.82.D0.BE.D0.B2_.D0.B8_.D0.BF.D0.BE.D0.B4.D0.B4.D0.B5.D1.80.D0.B6.D0.BA.D0.B0).
Так вот, как Марк получает прибыль или хотя бы компенсирует свои денежные вложения?
Пы.Сы.: Я не собираюсь подсчитывать чужие деньги, меня интересует способ заработка на подобных проектах.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Приведем пример RedHat. Да, сам линукс от них бесплатный, но продается поддержка. Большие дяди в больших корпорациях любят это. Почему? А все очень просто. Покупает он Линукс у Редхата, все работает и все прекрасно. А в один день админы все резко заболели, а сервера стали. Минута простоя - куча денег. Дядя просто звонит в Редхат и говорит "не работает" и Редхат высылает своих спецов, которые постараются все починить, и админов научить. В любое время суток. И пусть такое может случится раз в год, но платить будут каждый месяц. Понятно, что цены гибкие и максимальное кол-во вызовов зависит от этого.

Вариант два. Обнаружена мегауязвимость. Сервера дяди под вопросом. Он звонит в Редхат и говорит "что делать?", а те - "а мы сейчас патчик делаем, через день будет накатывать".

Следующим средством прибыли является сертификация и обучение. Тут все понятно.

И ещё один способ. Припустим компания X (тут и далее все имена компаний выдуманные и любое совпадение случайно и не преднамеренное) решила сделать суперноутбук. Начинила его самой последней техникой. Поставила туда Linux, а он "из коробки" не работает. Нужно настраивать и настраивать. Понятно, что это очень плохо (ну кроме как для некоторых гиков, которым только дай понастраивать). И они идут в компанию Y, которая делает Linux и говорят "а сделайте так, что бы ваш линукс на нашем ноутбуке заводился с пол пинка, из коробки! Инструкций для старых версий наделайте, патчей. А мы вам за это денежки подкинем". В результате все счастливы.

И напоследок, не нужно забывать о благотворительных фондах и пожертвованиях.

Вот так, с миру по нитке и зарабатывают производители Linux.

Comment: RedHat...

Comment: =) Читая между строк: чем больше проблем создает опенсорс-продукт заказчику, тем больше денег у опенсорс-разработчиков?)

Comment: нет, тем больше шансов, что либо сменят продукт. Благое дело, линуксов много разных. 
Если же это просто опенсоурс и альтернативы нет, то часто дешевле форкнуть.

Answer (score 2):

бесплатный софт наверное платной поддержкой?

Comment: Думаете именно это является основным источником дохода?

Answer (score 2):

Вообще, поодержка и сопровождениеп программных продуктов у Canonical куда дороже, чем у мелкомягких. И заработок строится именно на этом.

Answer (score 1):

Бесплатный софт это побочный продукт основной деятельности - **решения реальных проблем заказчика**

Comment: А кто заказчик в данном случае?

Comment: Не знаю. Шаттлворт вообще человек с интересной биографией.

Answer (score 1):

[Стоимость техподдержки настольных систем](http://www.ubuntu.com/business/services/desktop)

[Стоимость техподдержки серверных систем](http://www.ubuntu.com/business/services/server)

[Стоимость техподдержки облака](http://www.ubuntu.com/business/services/cloud)

[Убунту шоп](http://shop.canonical.com)

Ну и плюс обучение,а также партнерство)))Я думаю на жизнь хватит)

Answer (score 1):

Мой ответ будет не точно по букве вопроса, но вполне возможно, я затрону тему, которая вполне может интересовать задающего. Так вот, вопрос не в собственном заработке, а вообще глобально, зачем и кем задвинута эта тема открытых проектов? Как получается у этих вездесущих продавцов, что из априори бесплатных продуктов вырастают многомиллионные корпорации типа гуглов? Глядя на тенденции развития open source проектов в инете позволю себе смелость внести некоторые предположения. 
Исторически складывается что практически любой нововведённый проект является open source. Это началось не с внедрением инета, а много много раньше.

Любой проект можно условно разграничить на несколько этапов.
Каждый характеризуется определённым состоянием и отношением к нему общества.

1. Разработка.  Общество ничего не знает о проекте и прекрасно без него обходится. Возможно желание эволюционного поступательного развития общества требует каких-либо новых открытий. Сама идея скорее всего рождается в оществе, на кухнях, собраниях, посредством обычного общения, либо как результат обыкновенного любопытства. На этом этапе подключаются ЭНТУЗИАСТЫ, через которых распространяется информация о новой идее. Во времени идея не отражается, она просто есть (куклов здесь нет (^..^)) ;-).
2. Внедрение. На этом этапе подключаются реализаторы этой идеи, ТЕХНИКИ, инженеры, изобретатели, люди с техническим складом, которые оттачивают идею, приводят к совершенству, иногда «форкая» разветвляя её в какую-нибудь новую другую идею.  Этот этап растянут по времени и очень дорог в ресурсах. Я имею ввиду не только (и вообще не) деньги, но также время и жизненные силы. Здесь прибыль если и возможна, то она часто мизерна и случайна.
3. Развитие.  До этого этапа доходит далеко, далеко не каждый проект. К тому же многие из прошедших первые два этапа уже могут быть видоизменены до такой степени, и отличаться от своих «абстрактных прототипов», что могут даже оказаться в другой отрасли. В любом случае право решать, умереть или пройти  стадию развития принадлежит в случайном порядке либо обществу,  либо фактору времени, либо  самому случаю (куклов здесь тоже нет (^..^)) ;-).
4. Развитый проект. Если же счастливый билет получен, то развитие подключает другие отрасли и сферы жизни, и проект распространяется повсеместно, становится обыденным, вплоть до устойчивого привыкания.
5. Контроль. Вообще параллелльно со всеми этапами происходит процесс отладки управления проектом. ПРОДАВЦЫ выявляют возможности управления, степень влияния и заинтересованности обществом.  Выявляются ключевые компоненты. При определёных обстоятельствах проект приобретает надстройку, или множество настроек, когда его уже нельзя относить к open source. На его жизнеспособность будет влиять инертность общества, заинтересованность,  степень его «потребительства» и соотношение цены-качества.
6. Упадок. Проект будет «закатываться» по причине появления (осознания обществом) более рационального подхода, и, как следствие, появления первого этапа следующего проекта. Также проект может быть отвергнут обществом по причине несоответствия проекта интересам общества. В частности, сам тотальный контроль может оказаться катализатором несоответствия. Обобщить эти причины можно одним словом «нерациональность».

Лампочка, нефть, автомобиль, радио, интернет, многоэтажки –всё это, по крайней мере на этапе внедрения выглядело как open source  проекты. Всё вышесказанное позволяет предположить, что за развитием любого мало-мальски подающего надежды open source, если не стоят, то по крайней мере следят серьёзные игроки (куклы здесь (^_,^), которые готовы  «сделать вам предложение, от которого невозможно отказаться». Неулыбчивые продавцы постоянно мониторят этот хаб, потому как здесь вероятны самые вертикальные профиты. Продуктовая ниша проектов, которые потенциально могут иметь коммерческие надстройки уже довольно плотно заполнена. Подозреваю, что процент действительно успешных проектов без перехвата управления очень и очень мал. 
Итогом всего этого могу только посоветовать заниматься open source, только если это Ваше непреходящее УВЛЕЧЕНИЕ! Само собой разумеется, если вы хотите запилить потенциально прибыльную «фирменную вещь», помимо самой идеи Вам необходимо выстраивать стратегию правильного маркетинга. 
Кроме того на open source  сидит много начинающих талантливых ребят, которые рассматривают эту площадку как возможность карьерного роста и получения приличного трудоустройства, но, думаю, что это немного не по существу вопроса.

Напоследок пару пословиц, для создания виртуальных картинок (образа).
А)Начинают РОМАНТИКИ (1,2), продолжают ПРАКТИКИ(2,3,4), заканчивают ЗЛОДЕИ(5,6).
Б)Энергия течёт туда, куда направлено внимание.
Также приведу здесь ссылку на статью по-видимому [авторитетного](http://netsago.org/cgi-bin/main.cgi?p=docs&did=3&d=1&lang=ru&hash=) в мире web источника. Познавательно и со знанием дела.

Успехов, и всего рационального!

Answer (score 0):

Если я не ошибаюсь, то основным спонсором компании Canonical является DELL.

Comment: Может я ошибаюсь, но это сути не меняет. Как с Ubuntu вытягивают деньги?